# Different components, same route in angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have multiple components and I would like for them to have the same route.
In particular, I have HomeComponent, ComponentA, ComponentB and ComponentC. Currently, my routes are:

```
{ path: "path", component: HomeComponent },
{ path: "componentA/:id", component: ComponentA},
{ path: "componentB/:id", component: ComponentB },
{ path: "componentC/:id", component: ComponentC},
```

The ids are unique, for example, for ComponentA is 1, for ComponentB is 11 etc.

I would like to have the same path for all of them, for example, "path" , followed by the :id . Is that possible?
Thank you in advance.

I tried redirecting and UrlMatcher.

Comment: If the ids are known for each component, why you don't just use it directly in the `path` value, i.e., `{ path: "same_path/1", component: ComponentA }, { path: "same_path/11", component: ComponentB }, ...`

Answer (score 2):

There are a handful of approaches you could take to this problem: [GitHub repo](https://github.com/PdUi/ng-multiple-client-mod-approaches/tree/master/src/app) with multiple examples.

What might work best in your case though would be to use the `matcher` property on the [Route](https://angular.io/api/router/Route).

For full transparency, I found this approach first in [Medium](https://medium.com/@lenseg1/loading-different-angular-modules-or-components-on-routes-with-same-path-2bb9ba4b6566)

You could use a function as follows:

```
import { UrlSegment, UrlSegmentGroup, Route, UrlMatchResult } from '@angular/router';

import { map } from 'rxjs/internal/operators/map';

import { appInjector } from '../../main';
import { ClientsService } from '../clients.service';

export function clientMatcher(segments: UrlSegment[], group: UrlSegmentGroup, route: Route): UrlMatchResult {
  let matchResult: UrlMatchResult;
  const clientsService =  appInjector.get(ClientsService);
  const subscription = clientsService.selectedClient
                                     .pipe(map(client => matchResult = client === this ? { consumed: segments } : null))
                                     .subscribe();

  while (matchResult === undefined) {}

  subscription.unsubscribe();

  return matchResult;
}
```

And then update your Routes to:

```
{ path: "path", component: HomeComponent },
{ path: "components", component: ComponentA, matcher: clientMatcher.bind('1') },
{ path: "components", component: ComponentB, matcher: clientMatcher.bind('11') },
{ path: "components", component: ComponentC, matcher: clientMatcher.bind('111') },
```